# Remove multiple non-alpha characters from the end of a string

Tags: r, regex, string

I am doing some data cleaning on a series of individual names in a data frame column. I want to remove non-alpha characters at the end of each name.

```
countries <- c("Senegal1345769", "Canada&", "Austria12", "Spain-", "Russia#$")
```

In the case above, I'd want to turn countries into:

```
[1] "Senegal"   "Canada"   "Austria" "Spain"    "Russia"
```

I could use `gsub()` with character specific patterns (e.g., `pattern = ",$"`) but I'm not quite sure how to do this for strings with multiple, varying trailing non-alphas (e.g., `"Senegal1345769"`).

What kind of pattern would be used to address this issue?

Comment: You can try `gsub("[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", countries)`.

Comment: `(?i)[^a-z]+$` but beware this doesn't check for alpha char's.

Comment: I think this works, @d.b! Thanks, everyone. I appreciate it. Quick side question: I initially used "[^:alpha:]+$"; why did this not work? Just trying to get a better sense of what went wrong with that.

Comment: There is no point replacing *zero* non-letter symbols at the end of the string. `[^[:alpha:]]*$` must be turned into `[^[:alpha:]]+$`, see my answer explaining why it should look like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial try with `[^:alpha:]+$` was almost correct. You just need to bear in mind that POSIX character classes (like `[:alpha:]`) should be used inside bracket expressions.

Use

```
countries <- c("Senegal1345769", "Canada&", "Austria12", "Spain-", "Russia#$")
sub("[^[:alpha:]]+$", "", countries)
## => [1] "Senegal" "Canada"  "Austria" "Spain"   "Russia"
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/tmIknd).

**Details**:

- `[^`  - start of a *negated bracket expression*

  - `[:alpha:]` - a letter POSIX character class...
- `]+`  -  one or more times
- `$` - end of string.

So, the `[^[:alpha:]]+$` pattern matches 1 or more chars other than letters at the end of the string.

In case this expression fails to work, you may also try a PCRE pattern:

```
sub("(*UCP)\\P{L}+$", "", countries, perl=TRUE)
```

See [another online R demo](http://ideone.com/yfiY4y).

Here,

- `(*UCP)` - makes the pattern Unicode aware
- `\\P{L}+` - 1 or more chars other than letters
- `$` -  end of string.